# Overload method in template child class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, function-pointers

I have the following Scenario:

I've got a child class looking like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Child : public AbstractBase {

   virtual void Test(T *obj, void (T::*ptr)(int)) {
      (*obj.*ptr)(5);
   }

}
```

And the Base Class looks like this:

```
class AbstractBase {
   virtual void Test(T*, ??) = 0;
}
```

Is there any possible way to fill the *??*, so I can override the method in my Child class?

What I'd ultimately like to do is to store lots of *Child* objects in one list (list< AbstractBase* >), but with different types (different Ts).

Using the class would look like this:

```
#include "Child.h"
class A {
    A() {
       AbstractBase *ab = new Child<A>();
       ab->Test(this, &A::foo);
    }

    void foo(int a) {}
}
```

Comment: You can make `AbstractBase` a template as well taking `T` as parameter. Though this would make each instantiation of `AbstractBase` differ from others. As alternative you can change function signature to accept an `std::function` instead.